# Possible ways to encrypt database password in Javalin framework

Tags: java, encryption, configuration, graphql, javalin

Update password configs to store encrypted passwords (instead of plain-texts) for Ignite DB

One type I know is AES,Is there any different techniques for encryption with pros and cons will be helpful.

Comment: Related: [How to encrypt database connection credentials on a web server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22817/how-to-encrypt-database-connection-credentials-on-a-web-server)

Comment: These is not completely related to the work I'm doing now. Could you able to help more?

Comment: Perhaps if you [edit] your question, you can provide more details and describe the specific problem you are facing. (If you ask for more general options and opinions, with pros and cons, there is a chance that your question will be closed for being off-topic.)

Comment: Having said that, the most general advice I can give you is to focus on protecting your server, where the password config file is stored, rather than on storing the password as encrypted text (you will still need to decrypt that string anyway - and if someone can access the server where that happens, there is not much extra value in having it encrypted in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest(and very common) way is to use [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) Password-Based Encryption.
e.g.

```
String pass = System.getProperty("MySystemPropertyWithPass");
String encryptedValue = "...";
StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
encryptor.setPassword(pass);
String decryptValue = encryptor.decrypt(encryptedValue);
```